# Why I can not set workbook variable if it is open already vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to write a macro in outlook. This macro will do some stuff on outlook. but also will modify an existing excel document.
the problem arise if the "Doc List.xlsm" is already open. if it is so, "Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks("C:\Doc List.xlsm")" is not working.

But if the document is closed, then "Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Doc List.xlsm")" is working. In other words, I am able to change the excel doc.

I dont understand what is wrong with the "Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks("C:\Doc List.xlsm")"

UPDATE: When I put some error handling, the following message I get:

Error(9): Subscript Out of Range.

```
...
Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
Dim ExWbk As Workbook
Dim ExSheet As Worksheet
....
Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
x = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Doc List.xlsm")
If x = True Then
  Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks("C:\Doc List.xlsm")
Else
  Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Doc List.xlsm")
  ExApp.Visible = True
End If
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that a new instance of Excel is always opened. And `Doc List.xlsm` will never be open in the instance (because you just launched the instance of Excel on your machine - via code). `Doc List.xlsm`, if open, will be so in an *existing instance of Excel*.

Therefore, you can use this to test if there is an Excel instance already open on your machine.

```
'initiate Excel object
On Error Resume Next
Set ExApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If ExApp Is Nothing Then Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
```

Now, I can't see your `IsWorkbookOpen` function, but you have to check if the workbook is open in the instance of Excel you just initiated, so make sure that happens.

Then the rest of your code becomes

```
If x Then
   Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks("Doc List.xlsm") 'no need to include directory path
Else
   Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Doc List.xlsm")
   ExApp.Visible = True
End If
```

On a last note, to be clear, even this could fail if there were more than one instance of Excel open on the machine when the code is and the `Doc List.xlsm` file is open in the other instance not picked up by the `GetObject` reference. But I won't go into how to handle that here.

Comment: It didnt work. It seems when the debugger comes to that line exit the sub. no more line of code is being executed.

Comment: @TiTus - Now I understand the issue more clearly. I will edit my answer now.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the explanations. I have been trying to figure it out for a couple of hours.